# Почему то выдает синтаксическую ошибку =

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

```
def first_of_all():
    return chek_1 = input("""
Осматривая комнату, ты нервно ходил взад перед по комнате. Первым делом
ты подошел к разбитому умывальнику и включил холодную воду. После того
как ты умылся, ты заметил, что под разбитым умывальником лежит алюминиевая
кружка.
1)Взять
        """)
i = firs_of_all()
print(i)
```

Выдает ошибку в функции. Пишет что = это недопустимый синтаксис(chek_1 = input).

Comment: потому что так оно и есть зачем вы приравниваете `input` просто напишите без него и все (ну в плане без не `chek_1 = input(...)`, а `input(...)`

Comment: Мне нужно присвоить chek_1 значение 1 от юзера. Что бы потом использовать в if.

Comment: тогда его в `return` не заносите, `return` он выводит значения а не присваивает и выводит, если вам переменная `chek_1` нужна за пределами функции то у вас уже будет другая ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что вы хотите использовать ввод для какого-то последующего теста, потому вам нужно сохранить его в переменной `chek_1`.

Тогда вместо синтаксически неправильного (так как `return` ожидает выражение, а не команду присваивания):

```
def first_of_all():
    return chek_1 = input("""
Осматривая комнату, ты нервно ходил взад перед по комнате. Первым делом
ты подошел к разбитому умывальнику и включил холодную воду. После того
как ты умылся, ты заметил, что под разбитым умывальником лежит алюминиевая
кружка.
1)Взять
        """)
i = firs_of_all()
print(i)
```

используйте

```
def first_of_all():
    return input("""
Осматривая комнату, ты нервно ходил взад перед по комнате. Первым делом
ты подошел к разбитому умывальнику и включил холодную воду. После того
как ты умылся, ты заметил, что под разбитым умывальником лежит алюминиевая
кружка.
1)Взять
        """)


chek_1 = firs_of_all()     # то же самое chek_1, которое вы хотели получить
print(chek_1)
```